# TPopupMenu and TMainMenu arrow on the right custom painted vs Windows theme?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-11-alexandria

I recently ported my C++ Builder 2009 project to C++ Builder 11 and I notice that the `TMainMenu` and `TPopupMenu` items with sub-items still get an old style arrow on the right.

The IDE, built on the same technology, shows a proper arrow

What am I missing or what am I not setting ?

I highlighted the arrows in yellow.  The right side is the IDE:

[image: Sub-item arrows]

Comment: When I create a popup menu (with submenu) on a form, the arrows are **old style at design time**, but **new style at run time**. I'm using Delphi 10.4 CE and running on Windows 10. Btw, for me, the IDE form designer shows the old style triangles, but in code view the new style. Go figure.

Comment: So weird ?  I'm on Windows 10 too.  For me it's old style during run time as well.  Whether I dynamically create a `TPopupMenu` or one at design time, fully populated.

Comment: Maybe it is a "work in progress"? I tested only in Delphi as I don't have the C++ CE version. It might explain the difference. Maybe you could report it to Embarcadero.

Comment: @Peter Is your app manifested to enable Visual Styles?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem is that I assign a `TImageList` object to the `TPopupMenu`.  The moment I do, the control becomes `Ownerdrawn` and the arrow is painted old style.  Same when I assign a `Style`.  The moment I assign a `Style`, the control becomes `Ownerdrawn`.  The IDE PopupMenu however also has icons and has a Style, yet the arrows are painted Windows style.  Is this a bug and should I report it, or is this a 'feature' ?  Another problem is that I use `Item->OnMeasureItem` to make the height a bit bigger.  This requires setting `OwnerDraw` if no ImageList is assigned.